# SwiftUI NavigationLinks in List load NSViewDelegate/NSViewControllerDelegate twice

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm currently getting my feet into macOS development and tried to wrap some AppKit components into SwiftUI. I'm using a sidebar navigation with `NavigationLink`s in a `List`. When using `NSViewRepresentable` or `NSViewControllerRepresentable` as destinations the `makeNSView`/`makeNSViewController` methods are being called twice. I guess it's a bug since it seems to be working fine when I wrap the `NavigationLink`s directly in the `NavigationView`? Has anyone else got this problem and can help me with a workaround until it is fixed?

A minimal implementation to reproduce:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    let title: String
    
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        print("\(title) make view called")
        return NSView()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    enum NavigationItem {
        case sel1
        case sel2
    }

    @State private var selection: NavigationItem? = .sel1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                NavigationLink(
                        destination: EmptyView().navigationTitle("Dashboard"),
                        tag: NavigationItem.sel1,
                        selection: $selection
                ) {
                    Label("Dashboard", systemImage: "globe")
                }.tag(NavigationItem.sel1)
                NavigationLink(
                        destination: ViewRepresentable(title: "TestView").navigationTitle("TestView"),
                        tag: NavigationItem.sel2,
                        selection: $selection
                ) {
                    Label("Dashboard", systemImage: "globe")
                }.tag(NavigationItem.sel2)
            }
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .navigationTitle("SomeApp")
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }.frame(minWidth: 1000, idealWidth: 1200, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 600, idealHeight: 800, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: No reproducible for me on 11.2.3